# Beta density function

Tags: probability-distributions, beta-function

In this problem, I need to use Beta density function to solve the integration.

$$
\int_{0}^{100}x^{2}\left(\,100 - x\,\right)^{2}\,{\rm d}x
$$

After applying $\,{\rm Beta}\left(\, 3,3\,\right)$ I got $2!\,2!/{5!}$. However there should be a factor of $100^{5}$ which I did not get in my answer.

I don't understand where this factor came from.

Answer (score 1):

This factor comes from the change of variable $t = x/100$ (recall that the Beta distribution is defined on $[0,1]$, not $[0,100]$ — you have to scale things down)
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{100} x^2(100-x)^2 dx &= \int_0^1 (100t)^2(100-100t)^2 (100dt) \\
&= (100)^2\cdot(100)^2 \cdot 100\int_0^1 t^2(1-t)^2 dt \\
&= 100^5 \int_0^1 B(3,3)\beta_{3,3}(t) dt = {10^5}{B(3,3)}
\end{align}$$
with $\frac{1}{B(3,3)} = \frac{\Gamma(3+3)}{\Gamma(3)\Gamma(3)} = \frac{5!}{2!\cdot 2!}$.